# Selling Partner API using command line interface or tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, command-line-interface, amazon-selling-partner-api

We're new to Amazon [Seller Partner-API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs). Need to invoke certain Amazon SP-APIs for an integration workflow. For some internal reasons, using [Amazon SDKs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/create-signed-request.html#code-signing-examples) is a secondary option. With our conventional approach, we're able to interact with most APIs, in this case the [AWS Request signing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing-aws-api-requests.html) & [Signature generation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html#signing-request-intro) is where we're stuck.

As per Amazon using SDK handles it all internally. Is it possible to use a command line utility like - [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/index.html) to interact with SP-APIs? Not sure if this is feasible. Found this - [amazon-sp-api](https://amz.tools/en/amazon-sp-api) but not sure if it is stable / reliable.

> I believe there should be ways to interact with SP-API from command line. If not, atleast there should be a tool that is able to produce AWS Request signature (given the request info, key etc...).

Kindly share your experience and expertise. We're new to AWS, so if I'm confusing AWS with SP-API (esp for Request signing - I believe both use the same mechanism) pls point it out.

Answer (score 0):

The link you shared to amz.tools does not look like a command line interface. It is just an SDK generated in NodeJS. There is not way to connect to the API via command line. You can use Postman if you want to avoid SDKs.
And yes, AWS is not the same thing as SP API.
You can search github for SDKs generated on other languages; some seem to have a lot of use.
We generated our own SDK in C# because others didn't fit out criteria.